# SharePoint - Display Templates - Getting Every Item in All Lists in Site

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, display-templates

**I'm trying to get every single item from all lists within a SharePoint site.**  All of the docs and answered questions I've found in order to do this usually explain how to get all lists or all items from **one** list, but not every item in all lists within a site context.

I have my code below and I am able to get all lists fine, my biggest struggle is getting the items and not only from the last list (for some reason, it kept on doing this as I tested in the console - this version would probably just produce null errors instead since I made changes from before).

```
var allInfo = "";

        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAllListsAndItems);

        function getAllListsAndItems() {

            var context = new SP.ClientContext('https://mysites.sprcompanies.com/personal/cnorman/charpractice/');
            var web = context.get_web();
            var lists = web.get_lists();

            context.load(lists);

            context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

            function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {            

                var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();

                while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var list = listEnumerator.get_current();                    
                    allInfo += " List: " + list.get_title() + "\n";

                    if (list.get_itemCount() > 0) {

                        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
                        query.set_viewXml('<View></View>');
                        var items = list.getItems(query);

                        context.load(items);

                        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

                        function onSuccess(sender, args) {

                            var itemsEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();

                            while (itemsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                                var item = itemsEnumerator.get_current(); 
                            }      

                        }

                        function onFail(sender, args) {
                            console.log('Request on items failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                        }
                    }      
                }

                console.log(allInfo);
            }

            function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                console.log('Request on lists failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            } 
        }
```

I know the general problem area is here:

```
var itemsEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();

    while (itemsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = itemsEnumerator.get_current(); 
    }
```

I originally had it append to `allInfo`, but all it does is produce 'not initialized' errors.  I first thought that I just wasn't loading the items properly, but after testing it in the console, it does display the item collection objects so that's why I think it has something to do with the above.

Couldn't I just use a `for` loop to cycle through the items instead?  I only need the titles of each item.  I tried a `for` and a `for in`, but it again results in errors.  So it's really how I'm accessing each item (using the wrong properties).  Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

So I put this in the item `onSuccess` block instead:

```
if (items.get_item("Title") == null) {
    items.get_data().forEach(function(item) {     
        console.log(item.get_item('URL').get_description()); 
    }); 
}

else {
    items.get_data().forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.get_item('Title')); 
    });
}
```

Both would get the 'title' of an item whether it's a regular item or a link item - the problem is that it only get the items of the last list and repeats those multiple times instead of going through every list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in how I got the answer:

```
        var allInfo = "";
        var listsArray = [];
        var itemsArray = [];


        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAllListsAndItems);

        function getAllListsAndItems() {

            var context = new SP.ClientContext(SiteURL);
            var web = context.get_web();
            var lists = web.get_lists();

            context.load(lists);

            context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFailure);

            function onQuerySuccess(sender, args) {            

                var listEnumerator = lists.getEnumerator();

                while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    var list = listEnumerator.get_current();                    
                    listsArray.push(list.get_title());      
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < listsArray.length; i++) {

                    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    query.set_viewXml('<View></View>');

                    itemsArray[i] = lists.getByTitle(listsArray[i]).getItems(query);

                    itemsArray.push(itemsArray[i]);

                    context.load(itemsArray[i]);
                }   

                context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);

                function onSuccess(sender, args) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {

                        if (listsArray[i] != "Master Page Gallery") {

                            allInfo += " List: " + listsArray[i] + "\n";

                            itemsArray[i].get_data().forEach(function(item) {

                                if (item.get_item("Title") == null) {
                                    allInfo += " \t Item: " + item.get_item('URL').get_description() + "\n";
                                }

                                else if (item.get_item("Title") != null) {
                                    allInfo += " \t Item: " + item.get_item("Title") + "\n";
                                }

                                else {
                                    console.log("Something's wrong with this one.");
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    }                                

                    console.log(allInfo);  
                }

                function onFailure(sender, args) {
                    console.log('Request on items failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                }             
            }

            function onQueryFailure(sender, args) {
                console.log('Request on lists failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }  
        }
```

So basically I had to push every list that was loaded into an array then use that to load items from each one at a time because originally looping through it did not work since it only picked up the last list.  This would produce a structure like this:

```
List
     Item
     Item
     ...
List
     Item
     Item
     ...
...
```